# How do I store this JSON object as a cookie and than read it in vanilla javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, cookies, node.js

I can actually seem to write it fine as a cookie like this:

```
 ["4c3dd477c441e17957000002","4c2ac3cc68fe54616e00002e","4c3dd477c441e17957000003","4c3dd477c441e17957000004"]
```

But how do I read the cookie?

I'm using node.js/express.js (and coffee script), and when I read it the cookie key the value I get is just the first value of the above array.

Do I need to parse it somehow? Or a more complex serialization/deserialization altogether?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the cookie is getting stored properly? What is the value of `document.cookie`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cookies are separated by commas, so when you store the JSON it is being broken up into multiple cookies. You will need to encode the JSON string some way before writing to the Cookie and then decode when reading.

For example, you could take the JSON string and replace the '","' parts like this:

```
// encode
mycookie = json.replace(/","/g, '"-"');

// decode
json = mycookie.replace(/"-"/g, '","');
```

Obviously this is no a general solution as you would need to insure that the strings being replaced do not appear in the content (even escaped)

Comment: Thanks!

I actually had to do mycookie = json.replace(/","/g, '"-"') but it worked like a charm.

Comment: This isn't ideal since you still have to come up with some kind of string to replace the commas with and hope that string doesn't appear in the values that are stored.  Instead a nice solution is to use encodeURIComponent() and decodeURIComponent() which will encode and decode the commas and other troublesome characters.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just encode like this:

```
// encode
mycookie = json.replace(/","/g, '"%2C"');
```

And no modification is needed in decoding

Comment: A small typo there... that should be "%2C" rather than "2%C".  Also you would need to decode it later... but then what if the original string happened to contain the characters "%2C" or other strings that look like hex codes?  A more correct solution is encodeURIComponent() and decodeURIComponent() (also mentioned in my other comment to the other solution posted here).