# How do I encode a JavaScript object as JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, checkbox, hashtable

Is there a good way to encode a JavaScript object as JSON?

I have a list of key value pairs...where the name is from a checkbox, and the value is either true or false based on whether the box is checked or not:

```
var values = {};
$('#checks :checkbox').each(function() { values[this.name]=this.checked; });
```

I want to pass these values into a JSON object so store into a cookie to render a table (Columns will be added according to what the user checks off).

Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: There's no such thing as a json object.  Are you trying to serialize values into json, or are you trying to pass values into a JavaScript object?

Comment: I want to be able to create a json file to store the values of the checkboxes so the users choices are saved in a cookie. I am new to json so I don't know whicH i want

Comment: possible duplicate of [storing and retrieving json objects to / from a cookie](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501968/storing-and-retrieving-json-objects-to-from-a-cookie), [serialize form to json and store in the cookie](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5458736/1048572) and [How do I store this JSON object as a cookie and than read it in vanilla javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3252400/1048572)

Comment: IE7 and below need the JSON2.js library and do not support this API natively. http://caniuse.com/json

Answer (score 150, accepted):

I think you can use [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify):

```
// after your each loop
JSON.stringify(values);
```

Comment: I put this in an alert() but nothing appears

Comment: @daniellanger - based on your comment, this is the answer.  You'll need to do some debugging to see why things aren't showing up

Comment: so how can I save this to a file/ store it as a cookie?

Comment: and just to clarify, where should this line be?

Comment: `
    var values = {};
    $('#checks :checkbox').each(function() {     
        values[this.name]=this.checked; }); 
    var jsonString = JSON.stringify(values);`
Then you can use
[document.cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.cookie) to create your cookie ...

Comment: IE 10 is giving: JavaScript runtime error: 'JSON' is undefined

Comment: Completely dependent on if your browser supports JSON objects.  IE is notorious for not supporting the JSON.xxx() protocol.  Be careful because if you're trying to support older browsers, you'll need a TRY/CATCH statement just to use JSON.strinify() with IE10 or less.

Comment: [The native JSON methods are supported by IE8 and above](http://caniuse.com/json). That being said, [in IE they are only available in Standards Mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10219398/json-is-undefined-issue-in-ie-but-not-chrome).

Answer (score 43):

All major browsers now include native JSON encoding/decoding.

```
// To encode an object (This produces a string)
var json_str = JSON.stringify(myobject); 

// To decode (This produces an object)
var obj = JSON.parse(json_str);
```

Note that only valid JSON data will be encoded. For example:

```
var obj = {'foo': 1, 'bar': (function (x) { return x; })}
JSON.stringify(obj) // --> "{\"foo\":1}"
```

Valid JSON types are: objects, strings, numbers, arrays, `true`, `false`, and `null`.

Some JSON resources:

- [JSON on Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JSON)
- [JSON on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_Object_Notation)

Comment: Well, they are called "objects" in javascript. But yes, boolean values can be represented in JSON.