# Symfony 2 send json by ajax

Tags: php, ajax, json, symfony

For the purposes of testing I'd like to send parameter of using ajax to Symfony controller but the controller can not read the request.
I Twig I'm trying to send the value of input element via ajax request to Symfony controller.
**Code in twig:**

```
<body>
<h1>JQuery Ajax Json example</h1>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#submit").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url:"/payu",
                type:"POST",
                data:{
                    customerIp:$("#customerIp").val()

                },
                dataType:"JSON",
                success:function(jsonStr){
                    $("#result").text(JSON.stringify(jsonStr));
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>


<div id="result"></div>
<form name="contact" id="contact" methode="post">
    customerIp:<input  name="customerIp" id="customerIp" value="123.123.123.123"/></br>

    <input type="button" value="submit" name="submit" id="submit"/>
</form>

<h1>{{ result }}Format Data{{ result }}</h1>
</body>
```

In controller action, I'm reading the request content and decoded it using json_decode function.
**Code in controller:**

```
 public function payuAction(Request $request)
 {
     $veriable=[];
     if ($content=$request->getContent()) {
         print_r($request);
         $veriable = json_decode(getContent(),true);
         print_r($veriable);
     }

     return $this->render('BartekPsiutekBundle:Default:payu.html.twig', array('result' => $veriable));
}
```

Comment: What is the output from `print_r()`?

Comment: In pritn_r() -ther is nothing and in $veriable there is only Array

Answer (score 1):

But in script in twig, there should be this below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#submit").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url:"/payu",
                type:"POST",
                data:{
                    customerIp:$("#customerIp").val()
                },
                dataType:"json"

            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I used this form in localhost without symfony and when data by using ajax it works.    $customerIp=$_POST["customerIp"]; $data=array(
            "customerIp" =>$customerIp)

Answer (score 0):

This is because, you send plain text. Your Ajax call requests the answer to be in JSON (with dataType). You cant define the sending format.

To encode your value use as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10919965/how-do-i-encode-a-javascript-object-as-json)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url:"/payu",
            type:"POST",
            data:JSON.stringify(values),
            dataType:"JSON",
            success:function(jsonStr){
                $("#result").text(JSON.stringify(jsonStr));
            }
        });
    });
});
```

and in your controller

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
var_dump($data);
```

Comment: "values" -> is there json ?  I thought that when I get data from twig to ajax script I could make json in ajax and send to controller ?

Comment: "values" is a javascript object, you have to create this object from form field data.

Comment: var data = $('input[name="customerId").val(); is this correct ?

Comment: "data" is a literal object, not just value. So you have to do
var data = {customerId: $('input[name="customerId").val()};

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access getContent, you've put the value of it in `$content` earlier. Strangely enough calling getContent like a function should return an error. The correct way of calling it is `$request->getContent()`

So instead of:

```
json_decode(getContent(),true)
```

You should see if this works:

```
json_decode($content,true)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should get your data by name, controller should look like

```
public function payuAction(Request $request)
{
    $variable = '';
    if ($request->request->get('customerIp') != null) {
        $variable = $request->request->get('customerIp');
    }

    return $this->render('BartekPsiutekBundle:Default:payu.html.twig', array('result' => $variable));
}
```

Since you are sending POST request, this is the way to get your data.
You can find documentation here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/http_fundamentals.html

Comment: I used this form that you wrote but $variable is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript/jquery code send your data as  [`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP)#Use_for_submitting_web_forms) type not as `JSON`. And to read post data in your controller use `$variable = $request->request->get('customerIp');`, as @Pitchwaiz mentioned in his answer.

Your javascript code could be like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#submit").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url:"/payu",
                type:"POST",
                data:{
                    customerIp:$("#customerIp").val()

                },
                success:function(data){
                    $("#result").text(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

And your controller code could be like:

```
public function payuAction(Request $request)
{
     $veriable='';
     if ($request->request->has('customerIp')) {
         $veriable = $request->request->get('customerIp');
         return new Response($veriable);
     }

     return $this->render('BartekPsiutekBundle:Default:payu.html.twig', array('result' => $veriable));
}
```

Controller check in POST data for variable named `customerIp`, if the variable is there the controller will send it back.

Comment: I checked this and $veriable does not have any value.

Comment: Add this statement at the top of the controller code to check if POST data are sent to controller or not: `var_dump($request->request->all());die();`

Answer (score 0):

I will intend catch value of parameters in html using ajax and on the controler(symfony) send data in json using curl.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#submit").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url:"send",
                type:"POST",
                crossDomain: true,
                headers: {
                    'Authorization':'Basic MTQ1MjI3OjEzYTk4MGQ0Zjg1MWYzZDlhMWNmYzc5MmZiMWY1ZTUw',
                    'Content-Type':'application/json'
                },
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                data:{
                    customerIp:$("#customerIp").val(),
                    merchantPosId:$("#merchantPosId").val(),
                    description:$("#description").val(),
                    totalAmount:$("#totalAmount").val(),
                    currencyCode:$("#currencyCode").val(),
                    products1name:$("#products1name").val(),
                    products1unitePrice:$("#products1unitePrice").val(),
                    products1quantit:$("#products1quantit").val(),
                    notifyUrl:$("#notifyUrl").val(),
                    continueUrl:$("#continueUrl").val()


                },

                beforeSend:function(){
                    console.log($("#customerIp").val());

                }

            });
        });
    });
</script>
<div id="result"></div>
<form name="contact" id="contact" methode="post">
    customerIp:<input  name="customerIp" id="customerIp" value="123.123.123.123"/></br>
    merchantPosId:<input name="merchantPosId" id="merchantPosId" value="145227"/></br>
    description:<input name="description" id="description" value="Opis zamówienia"/></br>
    totalAmount:<input  name="totalAmount" id="totalAmount" value="1000"/></br>
    currencyCode:<input  name="currencyCode" id="currencyCode" value="PLN"/></br>
    products1name:<input  name="products1name" id="products1name" value="Produkt 1"/></br>
    products1unitePrice:<input  name="products1unitePrice" id="products1unitePrice" value="1000"/></br>
    products1quantit:<input  name="products1quantit" id="products1quantit" value="1"/></br>
    notifyUrl:<input  name="notifyUrl"  id="notifyUrl" value="http://shop.url/notify" /></br>
    continueUrl:<input  name="continueUrl" id="continueUrl" value="http://shop.url/continue" /></br>

    <input type="button" value="submit" name="submit" id="submit"/>
</form>
```

In Controller in symfony

```
public function sendAction(Request $request)
    {
        print('Jestem tutaj');
        $variable = '';
        $merchantPosId='';

        if ($request->request->get('customerIp') != null) {
            $variable = $request->request->get('customerIp');
        }

        if ($request->request->has('merchantPosId')) {
            $merchantPosId = $request->request->get('merchantPosId');
        }
        if ($request->request->has('merchantPosId')) {
            $merchantPosId = $request->request->get('merchantPosId');
        }
        if ($request->request->has('description')) {
            $description = $request->request->get('description');
        }
        if ($request->request->has('totalAmount')) {
            $totalAmount = $request->request->get('totalAmount');
        }
        if ($request->request->has('currencyCode')) {
            $currencyCode = $request->request->get('currencyCode');
        }
        if ($request->request->has('products1name')) {
            $products1name = $request->request->get('products1name');
        }
        if ($request->request->has('products1unitePrice')) {
            $products1unitePrice = $request->request->get('products1unitePrice');
        }
        if ($request->request->has('products1quantit')) {
            $products1quantit = $request->request->get('products1quantit');
        }
        if ($request->request->has('notifyUrl')) {
            $notifyUrl = $request->request->get('notifyUrl');
        }
        if ($request->request->has('continueUrl')) {
            $continueUrl = $request->request->get('continueUrl');
        }
        if (isset($variable)) {
            $data = array(
                "customerIp" => $variable,
                "merchantPosId" => $merchantPosId,
                "merchantPosId" =>$merchantPosId,
            "description=" =>$description,
            "totalAmount=" =>$totalAmount,
            "currencyCode=" =>$currencyCode,
            "products"=>array(
                "name" =>$products1name,
                "unitPrice"=>$products1unitePrice,
                "quantity" =>$products1quantit
            ),
            "notifyUrl=" =>$notifyUrl,
            "continueUrl=" =>$continueUrl

            );
            $data_string = json_encode($data);
            $ch = curl_init('https://secure.payu.com/api/v2_1/orders');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                'Content-Type: application/json',
                'Authorization:Basic MTQ1MjI3OjEzYTk4MGQ0Zjg1MWYzZDlhMWNmYzc5MmZiMWY1ZTUw'
            ));
            $contents = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);

        }


        print_r($variable);
        return $this->render('BartekPsiutekBundle:Default:send.html.twig',array('result' => $data_string));
    }
```