# Why I Can't Write Objects in <li> Tag

Tags: html, json

When I writing my JSON data to

HTML tag it's writing but don't write object. It's write [object Object]:

```
○Data1     ○wash dishes         ○[object Object]
           ○find some break     ○[object Object]
```

I'm trying to do

lists with pointing JSON database but it's looks like that. I'm calling my JSON with that code:

```
var db_note = objpick(data);

db_note.date.forEach(function(element) {
tabledatednote.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeend',"<li>" + element + " </li>");
/* I just writed to this part because is just changing "no_date.>date<" part while displaying other JSONs */
});
```

> objpick.js is an external file

```
function objpick(data){
for(i in data){ var result = data[i] }
return result
};
```

> and there is my JSON database

```
{
"nodate": ["wash dishes", "find some bread"],
"date": [{"01/01/2077" : "Cyberpunk Meet"}, {"25/05/2005" : "Buney?"}],
"bookmark" : ["Data1"]
}
```

Comment: Please update the question to include a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I think a runnable example not needed because I think there is a little tricky function to fix this issue. Also just object part has issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately what's being displayed is a string.  So the code converts whatever you want to display to a string.  For simple values, this conversion is easy.  It's consistent and obvious what the resulting string is for a single value.

But objects are not simple values.  They are potentially complex.  And unless otherwise defined on your object(s), the *default* string representation for an object is: `[object Object]`

Some of the things you are display are values:

```
"find some bread"
```

But some of them are objects:

```
{"25/05/2005" : "Buney?"}
```

For the objects, you'd need to tell the code how to display it.  Some options I can think of are:

- Manually.  For example, check if a certain property exists on the object and, if it does, display that property's value.
- [JSON-encode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10919965/328193) the object and display the resulting JSON string.
- [Override `.toString()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6307514/328193) on your object(s).

Which you choose is up to you, and for the same reason that you're seeing the current default behavior... Because only you know how you want/expect that object to be displayed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I maked a function forEach key. After I displayed my JSON. I appreciate it mate